# 404 error for category permalinks in subfolder multisite

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have a multisite WordPress 3.1, using subdirectories to separate the individual sites.
For some reason category permalinks don't work, I get 404 errors for every category page. The same goes for tag pages.

I have tried resetting .htaccess file to the default one mentioned here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network#.htaccess_and_Mod_Rewrite

I have tried changing the theme to Wordpress default, same error.

I deactivated all plugins, same error.

I use permalinks /%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/ and default category and tag base.
Note: If I change permalink to default, IT WORKS! But I don't want the `http://site/?p=123` links.

Comment: I have also tried removing rewrite_rules and _transient_rewrite_rules from the database, from the wp_xx_options table, and then resaved the permalink settings. Did not help.

Answer (score 4):

same problem here. for some reason you have to reset the permalinks per blog again. what helped me is:, login as admin, chmod the .htaccess, goto permalinks, choose and save the permalink structure and chmod the .htaccess to the default. full article @ http://www.squidoo.com/wordpress-not-found-error-fix.  on wordpress i found this article: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/post-title-links-do-not-work-404-problem-page-not-found. hope it helps you.

Comment: This worked for me. In case you have a lot of sites, you can use the `wp rewrite flush` command in combination with the  `--url` parameter to write a quick script.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself by adding the rewrite rules to the Apache SSL configuration under the Directory tag. Best of luck

Comment: Did you add them in the VirtualHost for SSL ?

Comment: I'm not using SSL, so no. Thanks anyway, might help somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling custom permalinks on WordPress with Nginx is bit tricky but easy. If you are using Apache with ‘mod_rewrite‘ enabled, WordPress will automatically add the the rewrite rules to your ‘.htaccess file’.

But, with Nginx you need to define the rewrite rules as well as add the ‘try_files’ directive to the Nginx configuration file for your domain/website. Otherwise, if you have enabled the custom permalinks on WordPress and you are using Nginx, then clicking the post URL will return a page with ‘404 Error‘.

You may find step by step detailed information here: [WordPress custom permalinks and Nginx](http://gettechgo.com/wordpress-custom-permalinks-and-nginx/)